Как переопределить метод через super() и можно ли это?
class Phone(Item):
    
    def __init__(self, name, price, quantity, number_of_sim):
        super().__init__(name, price, quantity)
        self.number_of_sim = number_of_sim
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}('{self.name}', {self.price}, {self.quantity}, {self.number_of_sim})"
    
    @classmethod
    def instantiate_from_csv(cls, data):
        with open(data, newline='', encoding="cp1251") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                cls(row['name'], row['price'], row['quantity'], None)

В классе Item нет number_of_sim, поэтому в класс-методе я добавил None в конце, но основная логика осталась такой же. Можно ли как то сделать в стиле DRY?

Прошу прощения, на stack overflow не так давно, не знал что надо принимать ответы, щас все решу

а как сделать так?

А может проще вынести cls(row['name'], row['price'], row['quantity']) в отдельный метод, который в наследование переопределить?

Если потомок не привносит ничего нового для метода, то не проще ли определить метод instantiate_from_csv в классе-родителе, а в потомке его просто использовать как есть? Зачем вам classmethod? Или вообще там вызывать Item или super, зависит от того, что вы ещё там планируете делать. А, или вам там обязательно объект текущего класса нужен? Надо ещё подумать, но что-то тут не то.

@CrazyElf а если ситуация такая, что для одного наследника нужны всё так же 3 параметра, а для другого (специального) уже 4.. но тут от контекста задачи конечно всё зависит  В общем, самое лучшее что придумал, это просто вынести конструктор в отдельный метод и уже его переопределять.

@Amgarak Ну да, обычная перегрузка метода. Зачем тут classmethod - непонятно.
